# Why there is a compiling error C2951 on a template operator but not on a template method?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My example code is below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NUM 1

class A
{
public:
    template <int N>
    int operator()() { return N; }

    template <int N>
    int f() { return this->operator()<N>(); }
};

template <class TC>
int foo(TC& tc)
{
    int a = tc.template f < NUM > ();        // OK.
    a += tc.template operator() < NUM > ();  // Error C2951 on VisualStudio 2013
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    A a;
    cout << foo(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know the compiling error can be avoid if replacing `a += tc.template operator() < NUM >()` with `a += tc.operator()<NUM>()` but this replacement can not be transplanted to Mac OS X's LLVM.

To my confused it's `A::operator()` and `A::f` are both member functions, why one compiles OK but one failed?

Comment: Compiles with GCC and Clang. I'd guess this is a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, GCC and CLang are both OK. My project has compiled for linux, android and ios and all are OK except VS.